# Populate Controller field from User claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, claims

How do I populate a controller field from user claims ? We use claims based authentication and I'm intrested in one of claim values say "Internal Id" which is send along with the user claims.

I'll need to extract this claim value and make it available for all my web api's. I know I can extract the value from the user claims using a loop within each of the action methods.

Is there is better way to do this ? Somthing like a attribute / value provider

Answer (score 0):

you can use an extention method on IIdentity to extract claims, this is how i do it:

```
    public static int GetInternalId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var storedClaim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirstValue("InternalId");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedClaim)) return 0;

        var value = Convert.ToInt32(storedClaim);
        return value;
    }
```

and you can call it everywhere you have access to Context object like Controller or ApiController

```
User.Identity.GetInternalId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom value provider that read the claims from the current user identity, then have a class that represent the list of key/value pair which is the claim/value in your action method.

This will make cause the value provider to fill the key/value pair and you won't have to write any additional code to have the user claims in any action method